# Loading Open Data Cube data to match a raster with geographic coordinates?

Tags: rasterio, xarray, open-data-cube

I would like to load a raster from a GeoTIFF file, and then load a time series of data from the Open Data Cube into the same CRS and resolution so I can use the raster as a mask. I can use the raster's `.geobox` to do this nicely when my GeoTIFF is in projected coordinates:

```
import xarray as xr
import datacube
dc = datacube.Datacube()

# Load raster and remove the redundant "band" dimension
raster = xr.open_rasterio("raster.tif").squeeze("band")

# Load data from datacube into raster geobox
ds = dc.load(
    product="s2b_ard_granule",
    measurements=["nbart_red"],
    time=("2018-01", "2018-02"),
    like=raster.geobox
)

# Use raster data as a mask
ds.where(raster > 500)
```

However, if my raster is in geographic coordinates (degrees), `datacube` will load with dimensions named `longitude` and `latitude`, not `x` and `y`. This means the dimensions no longer match the dimensions in raster, which prevents me from using it as a mask in the final step.

I've tried simply re-naming the dimensions in ds using `ds.rename({'longitude': 'x', 'latitude': 'y'})`. This fixes the immediate problem and allows me to use the raster data as a mask, but ds  still has a `.geobox` with dimensions named `longitude` and `latitude` after the rename which now don't match the `xr.DataArray`'s dimensions. This causes further issues downstream where I want to use the `.geobox` for other steps.

Is there:

1. Any way to load data from `datacube` to match a raster `.geobox`, but not switch to the longitude and latitude  dimension names even if the raster has geographic coords?
2. If not, is there any way to completely rename the coords so that they are renamed in both the `xr.DataArray` and the `.geobox`?